# python3 manage.py migrate got an error

Tags: python, django

I just started a new project and change database engine

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
    'NAME': 'mysite',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}
then after running python3 manage.py migrate i got an error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/base.py", line 177, in _execute_wrapper
    return method(query, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 434, in _handle_result
    self._handle_noresultset(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 404, in _handle_noresultset
    self._warnings[0][1], self._warnings[0][2])
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1265: Data truncated for column 'applied' at row 1
```

Comment: It looks like you shortent a field `applied` and the data does not fit in there anymore.

Comment: i hadn't installed my apps,just use 'django.contrib.admin','django.contrib.auth',and so on,how to change the the type of 'applied'?

Answer (score 1):

You have to:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

And then:

```
python3 manage.py migrate
```

Then you can safely start the server again

Hope this helps

Comment: unluckily,it doesn't work. if i use sqlite3,it works well.

Comment: It did not work for me, either.